# Ember.js hasMany relationship data display using fixtures

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to display data from hasMany relationship using fixtures. My code is available here: http://jsbin.com/xijewu/8/edit

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="item">
  <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
  <p>{{ description }}</p>

    {{#each comment in model.comments}}
      {{ comment.content }}
    {{/each}}

</script>
```

But it seems to be not displaying the data. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a related discussion here: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/what-is-an-async-relationship-async-true-vs-async-false/4107/6  I added the aync: true option and it's working now!

```
comments: DS.hasMany('comment', {
  async: true
})
```